# Best open-source javascript tree?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tree, ajaxcontroltoolkit, widget

Could you propose **open source, but commercial-friendly licensed (non-GPL)** Javascript trees?

Please take into account that I need it for an existing Web application, so I am not sure whether other tools such as GWT or Echo would be appropriate.

I have already checked:

- Dojo Tree
- jQuery.Dynatree.js (JQuery)
- JSTree (JQuery)
- Mif.Tree (Mootools)
- YUI Tree (Yahoo User Interface)

I have ruled out DHTMLX and ExtJS (both GPL, they require the whole project to be GPLed).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

**UPDATE:**
This question is old, the above list should no longer be taken into account. I'm sure there are more and better alternatives now.

Comment: Reads like you've done your due diligence!

Comment: were you able to find one ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and sorry for the delay. Among the above trees we chose JSTree, but at the end we used JSF and the component library Richfaces, which also includes a tree.

Comment: Would be nice to hear what you found wrong with the ones you listed :-) (Before I have to make the same mistakes you did..) I also found this unordered list: [jQuery Plugin Registry tagged "tree"](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/tree/)

Comment: Consider visiting my own Tree Class. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree help/sugguestions will be appreciated.:)

Answer (score 4):

[jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) seems best.

- Open source: MIT license
- Features: lazy loading, context-menu, keyboard navigation, drag & drop, inline editing, customizable, CDN hosted.
- Stackoverflow has 2,045 questions [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstree)
  with jsTree
- Alexa page rank of jstree.com is better than others

Other close contenders:

1. [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) (upgraded version of Dynatree)
2. [zTree](https://www.treejs.cn/v3/main.php#_zTreeInfo)

Answer (score 1):

I use this one:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this component:
https://github.com/u1ui/tree1.el

Its easy as:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/u1ui/tree1.el@x.x.x/tree1.min.css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/u1ui/tree1.el@x.x.x/tree1.min.js" type=module></script>


<u1-tree1 aria-expanded=true>root
    <u1-tree1>Folder 1
        <u1-tree1>File 1.1</u1-tree1>
    </u1-tree1>
    <u1-tree1>Folder 3
        <u1-tree1>File 3.1</u1-tree1>
        <u1-tree1>File 3.2</u1-tree1>
    </u1-tree1>
</u1-tree1>
```